# Java start internal File

Tags: java

im working on a small program and i want to start a included Program like a .exe or something else.

I have build a small GUI where you press a button to start the internal program. But my biggest Problem is that i didnt know how to do it. I had found some for external Files but nothing for internal stuff.

Can anyone help me :?

I had tried just before things like:

```
String str = this.getClass().getResource("src/tools/.../program.exe").toString();
prc = new ProcessBuilder(str).start();
```

But there i get only nothing or a NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

you can use java.awt.Desktop

```
public static void open(File document) throws IOException {
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.open(document);
}
```

you pass in the file path to what you wan to open as a `File` object

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a file from inside the JAR file. You have to extract it in a (temporary) directory. After that you can execute it like any other program.

Comment: ookay. Thanks to your answer. Did you have any idea how to do it in a fast way? (im not a pro and i have no ide how to extract something in temorary directory)

Comment: @AkEgo With [`Files.createTempDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)